# Regarding a warning message of "A classpath variable is deprecated"

Tags: java, eclipse

After importing a Java project in Eclipse, I got the following warning message:

```
Classpath variable 'JRE_LIB' in project 'scheduleDemo' is deprecated. Use the JRE system Library instead.
```

What does this warning message mean, how can I remove this message?

Comment: @bit-question it means that the project you imported is linked to an 'invalid' jre, right click your project, build path, and update the jre reference

Comment: How this problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `JRE_LIB` is deprecated. This is a `Classpath` validation message

To solve the problem you could go to the `Java Build Path` property page and click `Library` 
tab and then `Add Library`